# How to fill string with repeating it characters by text length?

Tags: c#

My `text` has 6 letters, my `key` has 4 letters. After XOR I get `newText` with only 4 letters. How can I make my `key` longer (repeat it till text length?

for ex.: `string text = "flower"`,`string key = "hell"` I want to make my string key = "hellhe" and so on...)

```
private string XorText(string text,string key)
        {
            string newText = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < key.Length; i++)
            {
                int charValue = Convert.ToInt32(text[i]);
                int keyValue = Convert.ToInt32(key[i]);
                charValue ^= keyValue % 33;
                 newText += char.ConvertFromUtf32(charValue);
            }
            return newText;
        }
```

Comment: Instead of `key[i]` use `key[i%key.Length]` and change your `for` loop to use `i < text.Length`. Look up "modulus" to see how this works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [remainder operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) (%):

```
 private string XorText(string text,string key)
 {
      string newText = "";
      for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
      {
          int charValue = Convert.ToInt32(text[i]);
          int keyValue = Convert.ToInt32(key[i % key.Length]);
          charValue ^= keyValue % 33;
          newText += char.ConvertFromUtf32(charValue);
      }
      return newText;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `StringBuilder` for string operations.

```
private string XorText(string text, string key)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) throw new ArgumentNullException("text");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key)) throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    int textLength = text.Length;
    int keyLength = key.Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < textLength; i++)
    {
        sb.Append((char)(text[i] ^ key[i % keyLength]));
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```